# Jenkins - Parsing throws exceptions. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: c#, jenkins

I cannot understand what should I do to configure a Jenkins job with Cppcheck, what is the real-best way? by nAnt, by Cppcheck plugin...? I attach the picture of my configuration. Do not hesitate to ask me for more information

[image: picture]

And that's the error that prints...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Pruebas_Carlos>[Cppcheck] Starting the cppcheck analysis.
[Cppcheck] Processing 1 files with the pattern 'cppcheck.xml'.
[Cppcheck] Parsing throws exceptions. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Pruebas_Carlos/cppcheck.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
Build step 'Publish Cppcheck results' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Publish Cppcheck results' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
```

there's some **UPDATED** **guide** where could get some tips about Jenkins for c# & c++ **please**? Thanks you very much

Comment: Jenkins documentation can be found here. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins There's also a specific part for .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry, I though it could be used for C#... My mistake